# How to add foreign key data in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Ok so i have created my table in the same database that is created by the `websecurity` helpers.

My class is

```
public class MovieModels
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

each movie is added by a user. Now the problem here is that i wan't to automatically fill the field of UserId based on the Id of user currently logged in. I think triggers would be used here but since i am absolutely new to asp.net mvc i don't how that can be done.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Update**

Ok so i have changed the code to

```
[ForeignKey("UserProfile")] 
    private int id_of_the_user;
    public int UserId
    {
        get { return id_of_the_user; }
        set { id_of_the_user = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId; }
    }
```

But now strangely the UserId field always shows 0 instead the id of user currently looged in. What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Might this work

```
   public class MovieModels
    {    
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
        public int UserId
        {
            get { return WebSecurity.CurrentUserId; }            
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's good for inserting, but not so good when someone else comes along to view the data...

Comment: Agreed - but the OP stated that he wants "to automatically fill the field of UserId based on the Id of user currently logged in" so perhaps this object is only an inbound UI-to-Database-Save object and is not used for retrieving data?